# Move to first character in line above in vi

Tags: vim, vi

When using vi in normal mode I've noticed that the enter key will bring the cursor to the first character of the line directly below.  This is a nice feature but I can't seem to find the key for doing the same thing upwards.  Anyone know either of a key that does this or how to create my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-` (minus) goes to the first non black character on a line going upwards.

One way to figure this out is by looking at the help for `<CR>` here you find

```
+               or                                      *+*
CTRL-M          or                                      *CTRL-M* *<CR>*
<CR>                    [count] lines downward, on the first non-blank
                        character |linewise|.
```

Which tells you that `+`, `<C-M>` and `<CR>` are equivalent. If you look at the section about this you would see

```
                                                        *-*
-  <minus>              [count] lines upward, on the first non-blank
                        character |linewise|.
```

which is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much.  If I wanted to change the key binding to Shift + Enter (say), is there a way of doing this in the vimrc file or otherwise?

Comment: @dsaxton `nnoremap <S-CR> -` unfortunately this most likely won't work as shift enter gets interpreted as enter. (It might work in gvim/macvim but most likely wont in terminal vim)